# Validating Properties with System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Validator

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have my Entity setup with [Data Annotation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx) validation attributes and i am trying to validate it using the static [Validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator.aspx) class but i am getting different exceptions, isn't this the right way to do it:

```
string _ValidateProperty(object instance, string propertyName)
        {
            var validationContext = new ValidationContext(instance, null, null);
            validationContext.MemberName = propertyName;
            var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
            var isValid = Validator.TryValidateProperty(instance, validationContext, validationResults);
            if (isValid)
                return string.Empty;
            return validationResults.FirstOrDefault<ValidationResult>().ErrorMessage;
        }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You havent stated what `Exception` you are receiving but it appears you are passing your instance to the `TryValidateProperty` method when you should be passing the *value* of the particular property.

Instead of

```
Validator.TryValidateProperty(instance, validationContext, validationResults);
```

try

```
Validator.TryValidateProperty(propertyValue, validationContext, validationResults);
```

you will have to pass `propertyValue` down to your method (or use reflection which will be slower)

eg

```
_ValidateProperty(someObject, "Field1", someObject.Field1);
```

Comment: Well, you are correct, i don't know where i have read to be careful not to pas the property value to TryValidateProperty but rather the actual object instance, nevertheless i should have done that, Thank you, i will give you the bounty when the site let's me after 12 hours.